# SELECT number of Logical CPU

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have written query that allows me to have an overview of all Azure SQL Database inside an Azure SQL Server; this query needs to be run on `master`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) -- 14 Days

SELECT
   database_name AS DatabaseName,
   sysso.edition
   ,sysso.service_objective
  ,(SELECT TOP 1 storage_in_megabytes FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs2 WHERE rs2.database_name = rs1.database_name ORDER BY rs2.start_time DESC)  AS StorageMB 
  ,CAST(MAX(storage_in_megabytes) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) StorageGB
  ,MIN(end_time) AS StartTime
  ,MAX(end_time) AS EndTime
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_CPU
  ,MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS Max_CPU
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [CPU Fit %]
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_IO
  ,MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS Max_IO
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Data IO Fit %]
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_LogWrite
  ,MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS Max_LogWrite
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Log Write Fit %]
  
  
FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs1
inner join sys.databases dbs on rs1.database_name = dbs.name
INNER JOIN sys.database_service_objectives sysso on sysso.database_id = dbs.database_id
WHERE start_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY database_name, sysso.edition, sysso.service_objective
ORDER BY database_name , sysso.edition, sysso.service_objective
```

Here the output:

[image]

I would like to add to this query how many logical CPU each database has.

I know that there is [query that I can run on each database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-dtu-to-vcore?view=azuresql) but I want to SELECT how many logical CPU each  database has by querying the `master` database.

Is there a way to grab such information form the `sys.` tables?

Or dynamic SQL is the only way to go?

**EDIT:**

@Charlieface suggested to use `SELECT cpu_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info` which is right but if I run it on `master` I only see the CPU used on master. I need to retrieve the CPUs used for each database.

Answer (score 0):

You add the following subquery:

```
(SELECT cpu_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info)
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-sys-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Further information for each processor can be got from [`sys.dm_os_nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-nodes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

---

It seems Azure Managed Instance only returns data for `master`. So you need to insert it into a temp table or table variable and join on that.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT ' + d.id + ', cpu_count FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.dm_os_sys_info
'   AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
'  )
FROM sys.databases;

PRINT @sql;  --your friend

DECLARE @tmp TABLE (db_id int PRIMARY KEY, cpu_count int NOT NULL);

INSERT @tmp (db_id, cpu_count)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


SELECT ....
  cpu.cpu_count
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN @tmp cpu ON cpu.db_id = dbs.id;
```

Comment: Thank you but both `sys.dm_os_sys_info` and  `sys.dm_os_nodes` returns the number of CPU only if you run that query on each database. I need to run this from `master`

Comment: ha,ha... I was thinking the same but `sys.resource_stats.cpu_limit` is for Managed Instances only, that `sys` table doesn't exists in Azure SQL Database

Comment: You are using it in your query above? And docs say the opposite: it's only available in SQL Database, not in Manage instance. `sys.dm_db_resource_stats` seems to be an alternative. Unfortunately I don't have an instance to test.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I was trying it right now. `sys.resource_stats.cpu_limit` works only on master but it return only 1 CPU and it doesn't returns the number of CPU per database. I will now test `sys.dm_db_resource_stats`. Thank you

Comment: nahhh, unfortunately `sys.dm_db_resource_stats` only returns statistics of the last hour. No info about the number of CPUs per database

Comment: You are going to need dynamic SQL then. See edit

Comment: Thank you, the code says `Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.`
Strange, it looks OK to me

Comment: Extra `)` sorry

Comment: Now I receive `The multi-part identifier "dbs.id" could not be bound.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Ambiguous column name 'cpu_count'.` I think `dbs` wasn't declared

Comment: The final `SELECT` you need to customize. Your original query had `inner join sys.databases dbs on rs1.database_name = dbs.name` so you would join onto that. And `cpu_count` is ambiguous as there are two tables with that column now, so you need to select `cpu.cpu_count`